# How can i read or intercept a packet sent by a flash application in the browser? (webscarab)

Tags: flash, browser, packet, intercept

I've been curious about how flash handles packets sent and received from a server. I've read that they should be encrypted and streamed through a secure SSL connection but I don't get why I still can't see them.

I'm using webscarab and so far have had no problem monitoring/intercepting HTTP packets. I see that when the flash application starts it creates `application/octet-stream` but this only connects to a resource server to load the assets (as far as I can see).

Am I going about this wrong? Is webscarab not up to the task? and to confirm: flash *usually* sends packets via HTTPS